# Parsing cvs diff output to get just the important information

Tags: linux

I have taken the cvs diff of two tags in a file output.diff. Now I need to parse that output.diff to get just the changes in spec file. The changes include added, deleted and modified packages. Also if a Patch (in any package) is added, deleted or modified and any version up of the package. Rest all the info of the diff output ( the lines added, line numbers and others) is not needed at all.

Please help. I am not getting through. It will be appreciated if bash script is suggested.

Comment: can u plz post few lines from output file `output.diff`

Comment: RCS file: /usr/tmp/dist/pkg/wide-dhcpv6/arm-target-dev-wide dhcpv6.spec,v
retrieving revision 1.34.2.2
retrieving revision 1.34.2.3
diff -r1.34.2.2 -r1.34.2.3
85,86c85,86
< --sysconfdir=%{arm_target_dev_sysconf_dir} \
< --with-localdbdir=%{arm_target_dev_localstate_dir} \
---
> --sysconfdir=/tmp \
> --with-localdbdir=/tmp \
99,100c99,100
< --sysconfdir=%{arm_target_dev_sysconf_dir} \
< --with-localdbdir=%{arm_target_dev_localstate_dir} \
---
> --sysconfdir=/tmp \
> --with-localdbdir=/tmp \
127a128,130
> * Thu Dec 05 2012 <Organisation>
> - Updated to sync with libnetparam IPv6 support

Answer (score 0):

A portion of the file output.diff is under :

Index: dist/pkg/libcurl/arm-target-dev-libcurl.spec

===================================================================

RCS file: /usr/tmp/dist/pkg/libcurl/arm-target-dev-libcurl.spec,v

retrieving revision 1.49.2.5

retrieving revision 1.49.2.7

diff -r1.49.2.5 -r1.49.2.7

6c6

< Release: 08010005

---

> Release: 08010006

11a12

> Patch4: curl-7.21.7-rfc2616.patch

43a45

> %patch4 -p1

115a118,120

> - Sat Dec 07 2012
>
> -Added curl-7.21.7-rfs2616.patch

=======================================================================

I want just the name of the spec file and name of the Patch Added, deleted or modified.
Also the last to lines ( change log )

Example as per the above file portion :

libcurl.spec

Patch4: curl-7.21.7-rfc2616.patch

Sat Dec 07 2012

-Added curl-7.21.7-rfs2616.patch